# Evaluate AuthorizeAttribute in action

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

One can authorize an action by using the [Authorize] attribute. But I want to only perform authorization on the action in specific conditions, so I cannot use this attribute. I don't think I am able to use IAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync as I don't have any policy names. Here's my service configuration in Startup.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");
```

So my question is, how can I move the [Authorize] evaluation into the action code?

Comment: How about `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AuthorizeAttribute` will be converted (maybe with others) into an `AuthorizeFilter` and this filter will be executed with some code that is not equivalent to the simple `IAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync`. But if you want to use that anyway, we can get the default policy (which is used by `[Authorize]` without any policy specified) by using the `IAuthorizationPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync`. After that you can authorize the `User` to get an `AuthorizationResult`. It is succeeded if the property `Succeeded` is true. Otherwise, you can have the detailed failure in the property `Failure` (of type `AuthorizationFailure`). Here's the code:

```
public class TestController {
     readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;
     readonly IAuthorizationPolicyProvider _authorizationPolicyProvider;
     public TestController(IAuthorizationService authorizationService,
                           IAuthorizationPolicyProvider authorizationPolicyProvider){
         _authorizationService = authorizationService;
         _authorizationPolicyProvider = authorizationPolicyProvider;
     }

     public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction(){
          var defaultPolicy = await _authorizationPolicyProvider.GetDefaultPolicyAsync();
          var authResult = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, defaultPolicy);
          if(authResult.Succeeded){
             //do something ...
          }
     }
}
```